# Find the range of $\left|\left|\sin x\right|\cos x+\sin x\left|\cos x\right|\right|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

Obviously the least possible value of the expression is $0$ when either of $cosx$ and $sinx$ is zero, but i have  trouble finding the maximum possible value of the expression. How do i proceed with this question, do I make cases and try to remove the  modulus expression  or what else?

Comment: If $0\leq x\leq \pi/2$, then both $\sin(x),\cos(x)\geq 0$, so this expression is just equal to $2\sin(x)\cos(x)$. Repeat for $\pi/2\leq x\leq\pi$, $\pi\leq x\leq3\pi/2$, and $3\pi/2\leq x\leq2\pi$.

Comment: Yes, i will try and give a update here. Edit: I got it, the maximum possible value is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than what @ndhanson3 suggests in the comments, there is perhaps a shorter method:

Note that

$$\sin x|\cos x|\leq |\sin x \cos x|=\frac {|\sin 2x|}{2}\leq \frac 12$$
Similarly $$|\sin x|\cos x\leq \frac 12$$
So $$\sin x|\cos x|+|\sin x| \cos x\leq 1$$
This value is attained at $x=\frac {\pi}{4}$.
Hence maximum value is $1$.

Comment: I suppose that your answer means that the given expression is definitely smaller than 1 in any case, but whether it will actually attain the value of 1 will have to be checked upon right? Since  it was relatively easier in this case to show that it is equal to 1 at x=$pi/4$, but is this viable for certain other situations?

Comment: The question asks about the absolute value of the function you're considering. So you should also establish that $-1$ is a lower bound.

Comment: @Bungo True, I should have pointed that out. OP, do I need to show it? You need to use the inequality $\sin x|\cos x|\geq -|\sin x \cos x|$ and proceed the same way.

Comment: Also, OP, yes you are correct. First I established that it is necessary for expression to be less than or equal to $1$, then showed that $1$ is also attained. For your second query it is difficult to suggest an approach without knowing the exact question, however often combining the terms using $\sin(x+y)$ formula could work for finding maximum value.

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta understood, thanks :)

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta No need to show that, not concerned about that part.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=\left|\sin\left(x\right)\left|\cos\left(x\right)\left|+\cos\left(x\right)\right|\sin\left(x\right)\right|\right|, X=(\sin x, \cos x)$ and $Y=(| \cos x|, | \sin x|).$ By Cauchy-Schwarz we have

$$0 \le f(x) \le ||X||_2 \cdot ||Y||_2 =1.$$

Since $f(0)=0$ and $f(\frac {\pi}{4})=1$, the continuity of $f$ gives

$$ f( \mathbb R)= [0,1].$$

Answer (score 0):

When  $\sin x\cos x\ge0$

$$|\sin x|\cos x|+|\sin x|\cos x|=|\pm2\sin x\cos x|=|\sin2x|\le1$$

which will occur if $\sin2x=\pm1\iff\cos2x=0\iff2x=(2n+1)\dfrac\pi2$ where $n$ is any integer

We have already attained minimum $(=0)$ for which can be the smallest  for  modulus of any number

Answer (score 0):

$\bigg|\sin\left(x\right)\left|\cos\left(x\right)\left|+\cos\left(x\right)\right|\sin\left(x\right)\right|\bigg| =\max(\sin(2x),0)$

so the maximum is $1$ at $x= \left(n+\frac14\right)\pi$ and the function looks like this blue line

[image]